# finder_sql does not parse string with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, finder-sql

I have the problem that the query I use for `finder_sql` is not parsed correctly before it is handed over to PostgreSQL resulting in a database syntax error.

To illustrate the problem I just used the example code from here:

> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

I only changed `class_name` to `"User"` as I don't have a person model but this does not matter here.

```
has_many :subscribers, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql =>
'SELECT DISTINCT people.* ' +
'FROM people p, post_subscriptions ps ' +
'WHERE ps.post_id = #{id} AND ps.person_id = p.id ' +
'ORDER BY p.first_name'
```

When I use this, I get the following error:

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT people.* FROM people p, post_subscriptions ps WHERE
ps.post_id = #{id} AND ps.person_id = p.id ORDER BY p.first_name
PGError: ERROR:  Syntaxerror near »{« 
LINE 1: ...ople p, post_subscriptions ps WHERE ps.post_id = #{id} AND p...
                                                         ^
```

As you can see `#{id}` is not replaced with the id of the object which then raises the PostgreSQL error.

Environment

- Rails 3.1
- rvm
- PostgreSQL 9.1
- Ubuntu 11.10
- Ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you're actually looking for is this:

```
has_many :posts, :finder_sql =>
    proc {"SELECT p.* from posts p join topics t on p.topic_id = t.id where t.id=#{id}"}
```

As of Rails 3.1 you have to use a proc instead of a string to use fields like `#{id}`.

See the issue here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3920

Comment: @stefan plz mark the correct solution, this one worked for me :)

Answer (score 8):

The documentation for `:finder_sql` is woefully incomplete and the example code is broken. As you have discovered, this:

```
has_many :subscribers, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql =>
  'SELECT DISTINCT people.* ' +
  'FROM people p, post_subscriptions ps ' +
  'WHERE ps.post_id = #{id} AND ps.person_id = p.id ' +
  'ORDER BY p.first_name'
```

will not work and, based on the ActiveRecord source, cannot work. If you check the source, you'll [see things like this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L373):

```
def custom_finder_sql
  interpolate(options[:finder_sql])
end
```

and then [`interpolate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb#L155) does this:

```
def interpolate(sql, record = nil)
  if sql.respond_to?(:to_proc)
    owner.send(:instance_exec, record, &sql)
  else
    sql
  end
end
```

so if your `:finder_sql` is just a string (such as in the example), then it is used as-is with no interpolation at all and you end up with broken SQL. If you want the interpolation, then you'll have to get `interpolate` to enter the first branch so you'd want a lamba for `:finder_sql` and a double quoted string inside the lambda so that `#{id}` will work:

```
has_many :subscribers, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql => ->(record) do
      "SELECT DISTINCT people.* " +
      "FROM people p, post_subscriptions ps " +
      "WHERE ps.post_id = #{id} AND ps.person_id = p.id " +
      "ORDER BY p.first_name"
end
```

That should get into the first branch inside `interpolate` so that the [`instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) call will be evaluated and interpolate the string within the context of the object in question. I'm not sure when `record` will not be `nil` so you might want this instead:

```
has_many :subscribers, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql => ->(record) do
      record = self if(record.nil?)
      "SELECT DISTINCT people.* " +
      "FROM people p, post_subscriptions ps " +
      "WHERE ps.post_id = #{record.id} AND ps.person_id = p.id " +
      "ORDER BY p.first_name"
end
```

And while we're here, please use explicit join conditions instead of implicit ones:

```
has_many :subscribers, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql => ->(record) do
      record = self if(record.nil?)
      "SELECT DISTINCT people.* " +
      "FROM people p " +
      "JOIN post_subscriptions ps on p.id = ps.person_id " +
      "WHERE ps.post_id = #{record.id} " +
      "ORDER BY p.first_name"
end
```

The blog you found about single/double quotes and `:finder_sql`:

> http://tamersalama.com/2007/05/17/finder_sql-single-vs-double-quotes/

is out of date and doesn't seem to apply to Rails 3+. The excerpts above are from 3.1 but the behavior you're seeing indicates that the code and behavior probably changed in 3.0 but the documentation wasn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you're hoping to hear but the problem is that you should be letting ActiveRecord do this work for you.

What you really want to solve this problem is to have these three files:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'people'
  has_many :post_subscriptions
end
# post_subscription.rb
class PostSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
# post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_subscriptions
  has_many :subscribers, :through => :post_subscriptions, :source => :user
end
```

Then you won't have to write any SQL at all. Just call `@post.subscribers` to get the full list of subscribed users.

Comment: Sort of. The real problem is that AR's documentation is incomplete and the examples in the documentation are broken (or perhaps just out of date and unmaintained). Using the standard Rails stuff is the preferred way but not always possible, if you need to use `:finder_sql` then it will almost certainly have to be a lambda instead of a simple string.